# Manage attribute fields ArcGIS Pro 2.0.1

Tags: editing, fields-attributes, arcgis-pro

I'd like to edit, create new and delete attribute fields using ArcGIS Pro.
I open attribute table using short cut Ctrl + M.
When I click Field View
[image: Field view]

So I try to add new, or any manipulation. But the most important question. **How to save edits**?
ESRI [tell](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/geodatabases/overview/create-modify-and-delete-fields.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_407738875C374AF1A9EDFBB97A11D5CB) me to click save. But where's "save" button?

Comment: Which of editing, creating new and deleting attribute fields using ArcGIS Pro do you wish to ask about in this particular question.  I have had no trouble doing any of those operations so once we know precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck your question should become very answerable.

Comment: I've unchecked Read Only tick – can't save. But Field was optional, not geometry or OID. I tried something more with different data – I can create new and calculate. Delete input after that. So it seems all is working. All I need is just to explore more.

Answer (score 1):

So I found save button in the ribbon menu

[image: The answer]

But save command is currently disabled due to my improper (I assume) changes. Description tells:

> Save is enabled when there are valid edits to the fields, but disabled
>   if the current project contains unsaved feature edits.

I tried many edits but all came to disabled save button.

---

So I have finally solved all my troubles. You can't save fields while editing. Just save editing and after that you can change fields options!